# I have created a space invader game and want to make it online using Flask. Is it a suitable approach?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pygame

The game is of 25 Level, each level consists of different enemies with different Shooting Lasers and health bar. So far the player spaceship has 5 powerups which becomes active as he shoots the enemies and a powerup image comes up.

Answer (score 0):

A web framework like Flask or Django is just for linking backend scripts and databases to a web page.
**Because PyGame will need a python environment to be run.**

1.You can either make a game using **Javascript** like **Phaser.js**.

2.Or you can create an executable file of your game using [**pyinstaller**](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and distribute those.

But personally the best choice for a browser game is using Javascript frameworks.

Comment: Can you explain how to use the .exe file with flask for web app.

Comment: Sure the general way of doing it is

open command prompt and pip install pyinstaller , once it is downloaded go to the program's directory and run 

pyinstaller --onefile "filename.py"

you will get your game in dist folder.

If you found it helpful please Upvote!!!

Comment: I mean to say how to use the .exe file in the flask app(not how to create .exe file)

Comment: I don't think that you can use .exe file on a flask app u can only distribte it.